# Make bootstrap footer stick at the bottom of content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It's been 3 days since I'm trying to make the footer stick at the bottom of webpage content. I know there are  a lot of similar questions but I couldn't find anything as the solution. Here's is my code:

```css
.container{position:relative;}
 footer{position:absolute;bottom:0;}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="col">
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
          <h1>contact us</h1>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `position:sticky;`

```css
container{position:relative;}
footer{position:sticky;bottom:0;}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col">
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <h1>contact us</h1>
    </footer>
</div>
```

OR use `position:relative` to `.container` with `.col{padding-bottom:5rem; }`

```css
.container{
position:relative;
}
.col{
padding-bottom:5rem;
}
footer{
   
   position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="col">
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
          <h1>contact us</h1>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Comment: No, I don't want it to be at the bottom of viewport. I want it to be at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be at the bottom of the page & not the viewport you have to set height for the content so that the `absolute` footer will be at the bottom.

Else change its relative `parent` class.
Here I set `body` as the parent for the `footer`

Try this..

```css
body{position:relative;}
.container{
height:800px;
}

footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="col">
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
              <p>content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
          <h1>contact us</h1>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

Comment: I want it to be just at the bottom of webpage. Not sticky

Comment: How can I make the height of container the height of viewport?

Comment: add `height:100vh`

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to stick to the bottom of the `container` use `position: relative` or just remove `position` entirely, same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below example for the same.

```css
 
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.demo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 64px;
  max-width: 640px;
  width: 94%;
}

.demo h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, a, assumenda. Quo architecto commodi vero, omnis amet accusantium at temporibus molestiae sed ipsum debitis culpa voluptate recusandae velit, deserunt sunt.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, a, assumenda. Quo architecto commodi vero, omnis amet accusantium at temporibus molestiae sed ipsum debitis culpa voluptate recusandae velit, deserunt sunt.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, a, assumenda. Quo architecto commodi vero, omnis amet accusantium at temporibus molestiae sed ipsum debitis culpa voluptate recusandae velit, deserunt sunt.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, a, assumenda. Quo architecto commodi vero, omnis amet accusantium at temporibus molestiae sed ipsum debitis culpa voluptate recusandae velit, deserunt sunt.</p>
</div>

<div class="footer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet</div>
```